# Regarding Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, error-handling

order.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderItems: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'OrderItem',
        required:true
    }],
    shippingAddress1: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    shippingAddress2: {
        type: String,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    zip: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Pending',
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    dateOrdered: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
})

orderSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

orderSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

order-item.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }
})

exports.OrderItem = mongoose.model('OrderItem', orderItemSchema);
```

orders.js

```
router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const orderItemsIds = Promise.all(req.body.orderItems.map(async (orderItem) =>{
        let newOrderItem = new OrderItem({
            quantity: orderItem.quantity,
            product: orderItem.product
        })

        newOrderItem = await newOrderItem.save();

        return newOrderItem._id;
    }))
    const orderItemsIdsResolved =  await orderItemsIds;

    let order = new Order({
        orderItems: orderItemsIdsResolved,
        shippingAddress1: req.body.shippingAddress1,
        shippingAddress2: req.body.shippingAddress2,
        city: req.body.city,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        country: req.body.country,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        status: req.body.status,
        totalPrice: totalPrice,
        user: req.body.user,
    })
    order = await order.save();

    if(!order)
    return res.status(400).send('the order cannot be created!')

    res.send(order);
})
```

```
const orderItemsIds = Promise.all(req.body.orderItems.map(async (orderItem) =>{
                                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

How to solve this error? could anyone please help me to find the error I can't find it I have tried in many ways but I failed to solve this.

Comment: The error means that there's no `req.body.orderItems` property. Use `console.log(req.body)` to see what parameters you're getting.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate middleware to parse JSON bodies?